# Как сказать «play again»

Tags: перевод

Would it be proper to say «играй(те) ещё раз»?

I have seen many examples in Russian literature of «ещё раз» used to indicate again or another time, but my confusion lies with the conjugation of играть. It seems to make sense it be conjugated in the imperative, but I have seen similar instances where imperative would make sense but is not used.

Comment: Do u want to build a question or an imperative?

Comment: If you open the site ya.ru you'll see that all links there are commands: "Найти", "Войти в почту", "Сделать стартовой" (if you add "Я хочу" to the beginning of this "command" you'll get a "I wish..." sentence). I think in your case it should be "Сыграть еще раз".

Comment: In almost all cases, an infinitive (personally neutral) form can fit: Play again - Сыграть еще раз. ("to give it another shot"). Question form does not change the words arranging, it is simply need to add a question mark: Play again? - Сыграть еще раз?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the prevous game was unsuccessful, incomplete, for instance, a draw, or a player left, or interrupted, but it is necessary to determine a winner:

> Играйте ещё раз! = "Play again, until the result is achieved"

If the prevuous game was successful and joyful,

> Сыграйте ещё раз! = "Play one more time, repeat"

Answer (score 3):

In case you are talking about game development translation issue, and more exactly about the button "Play again?", then there are several possibilities how to translate it:

- Сыграть ещё? - (To) Play again?
- Новая игра.  - New game.
- Повторить попытку. - (To) Repeat the attempt.
- Сыграть заново.(?) - (To) Play again?
- Попробуйте ещё раз. - Try again.

I haven't met imperative like "играйте ещё раз!" though. Maybe I am not so well-rounded in Russian games. =)

As you can see from the examples above, infinitive is used often when referring to this button. But, if it's not what you were asking about, then sorry!

Comment: If this is a button, I would definitely translate it as «Начать новую игру».

Answer (score -1):

You should use words "Играть снова"

Comment: Thank you for participation, but this answer adds nothing new to the previous answers.